# Uploading 3D interactive MATLAB mesh plot to ShareLaTeX

Tags: matlab, pdf, plot, latex, mesh

I've been working on a project about magnetic fields for my university, and at some point in the MATLAB simulation code I'm creating an interactive mesh plot of the magnetic field at certain points in space. I was wondering as to how I should convert this MATLAB figure to something that I can integrate in a LaTeX pdf. I've read about the media9 package, and I think I'll manage to figure the inserting the file in my .tex file out once I get the figure in an "exportable" form, but I'm not sure as to what I should convert my plot to and how I can do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want an interactive pdf? I did not know that was possible... Isnt a pdf by default printable? i.e. something static, a document.

Comment: I've read about people having interactive plots in their pdfs. I was skeptical at first too but there seems to be a way of doing that. This for example : https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37640-export-figure-to-3d-interactive-pdf?

Comment: Holy cow, that actually works. Interesting

Comment: Yes it looks like that somehow works. I'm not sure about how it'll get printed though.

Comment: It will probably not involve .fig files, because you need to have the MATLAB graphics engine to run them, and I doubt you can actually put that in a pdf

Comment: Corrected that in the title, thanks.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Indeed, animated graphics can be generated in `LaTeX` with the `animate` package. Have a look at [this cool paper](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2010-1/sunol/sunol.pdf) by one of my professors. Cheers.